# Using for loop to stylize strings into ASCII art

Tags: python, ascii

I am trying to get this output:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P|Y|T|H|O|N|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Is it possible to get that output without adding new lines in the code?

```
def art(name):
  for i in range(len(name[0]), len(name) + 1):
    head = "+" + i * "-+"
    middle = "|" + i * "{}|".format(name[0].upper())
    bottom = "+" + i * "-+"
  print(head + "\n" + middle + "\n" + bottom)

art("Python")
```

Actual output:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P|P|P|P|P|P|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

I can't figure out how to manipulate it in order to get it to work. I've tried to use use `index()` and `i` as a variable but I get errors such as:  "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: Why are you providing your actual and target output as screenshots instead of text? (edited: fixed; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122 describing why we frown on screenshots of text)

Comment: Put a `print(repr(i))` into the loop or, even more useful, learn to use a debugger to step through the code. For the latter, try to find video tutorials for your IDE. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded the index `0` when you're looking up the character to print:

```py
def art(name):
  for i in range(len(name[0]), len(name) + 1):
    head = "+" + i * "-+"
    middle = "|" + i * "{}|".format(name[0].upper())
                                         ^-- here
    bottom = "+" + i * "-+"
  print(head + "\n" + middle + "\n" + bottom)

art("Python")
```

Instead, you can use `i` to reference the actual character in `name`:

```
middle = "|" + i * "{}|".format(name[i].upper())
```

You also have an error in your `range`. There is no need to use `len(name[0])` - this will always be `1`, and will cause your loop to run one iteration longer than the length of `name` (since indexes start on `0`). This is the cause of your `IndexError`.

Instead, use `0` as the start - which is the same as not giving a start argument at all:

```
for i in range(len(name)):
```

But you don't actually need the index; there is no need to iterate over the `name` to do what you want. You can instead join each letter in `name` with `|` as the separator. The header/footer can be created by repeating `+-` the same amount of time as the length of `name`. So your loop can be replaced with:

```
print('+-' * len(name) + '+') 
print('|' + '|'.join(name.upper()) + '|')
print('+-' * len(name) + '+')
```

.. or assigned to `head`, `middle`, `bottom` if you want that instead.

Answer (score 0):

`head` and `bottom` don't need to be in the `for` loop, because they calculate the full string all at once. For that matter, because they're the same string, there's no reason for them to be two separate variables at all.

Your loop doesn't need to loop over indexes -- it can loop over characters, so you can directly add those characers yourself; and using an f-string is somewhat unnecessarily overcomplicated.

Anyhow -- if you're going to be using a loop, you should be additively constructing your string; just overwriting the whole thing on every iteration makes there no point to using a loop at all.

```
def art(name):
  head = "+" + len(name) * "-+"
  middle = ''
  for character in name:
    middle += '|{}'.format(character.upper())
  print(head + "\n" + middle + "|\n" + head)

art("Python")
```